# Take value from stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net

I want create c# helper from stored procedure

The stored procedure end of code.

When I run code I have error procedure or function has too many arguments specifield

```
public int xda_sp_GetTagWithComponent(string ComponentNo)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};Password={1};User ID={2};Initial Catalog={3};Connection Timeout={4}", DataSource, Password, UserID, InitialCatalog, ConnTimeOut));
    int ReturnResult;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        // 1.  SP name
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("xda_sp_GetTagWithComponent", conn);

        // 2. to execute a stored procedure   
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // 3. add parameter 
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ComponentSerialNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 16).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters["@ComponentSerialNo"].Value = ComponentNo;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SerialNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 16).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters["@SerialNo"].Value = "";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@returnResult", SqlDbType.Int, 100).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        //4. Execute
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //5. Get Result
        ReturnResult = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@returnResult"].Value);
    }

    catch
    {
        ReturnResult = 0;
    }

    finally
    {
        // Close the connection
        if (conn != null)
        {
        conn.Close();
        }
    }

    return ReturnResult;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the specific error that you're seeing?

Comment: ...can you paste the stored procedure code....?...

Comment: Your 2nd parameter has direction of Output, shouldn't it be InputOutput?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the last parameter as `ParameterDirection.Output`, but this means that your stored procedure needs to declare it as OUTPUT in the list of incoming parameters. Something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xda_sp_GetTagWithComponent 
    @ComponenSerialNo varchar(16),
    @SerialNo varchar (16),
    @returnResult INT OUT
AS
    .....
```

But, if you, instead, have only the first two parameters and, given the name, you want assign to @returnResult the value of a RETURN statement inside the stored procedure then you should declare it as

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@returnResult", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = 
                                    ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@SerialNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 16).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters["@SerialNo"].Value = "";
```

Instead use

```
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@SerialNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 16).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
                cmd.Parameters["@SerialNo"].Value = "";
```